# Custom Pagination in Shortcode with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Trying to add custom pagination within a visual composer shortcode.  The `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_previous_posts_link()` functions are working fine, but when I try to add the pagination function, nothing is returned.  No errors, however.  Here's what I've got:

**Pagination Function:**

```
function custom_pagination( $numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='' ) {

    if ( empty( $pagerange ) ) {
        $pagerange = 2;
    }
    global $paged;
    if ( empty( $paged ) ) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    if ( $numpages == '' ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if ( ! $numpages ) {
            $numpages = 1;
        }
    }

    $pagination_args = array(
        'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format'          => 'page/%#%',
        'total'           => $numpages,
        'current'         => $paged,
        'show_all'        => False,
        'end_size'        => 1,
        'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
        'prev_next'       => True,
        'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
        'type'            => 'plain',
        'add_args'        => false,
        'add_fragment'    => ''
    );

    $paginate_links = paginate_links( $pagination_args );

    if ( $paginate_links ) {
        echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
        echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . 
            " of " .  $numpages . "</span> ";
        echo $paginate_links;
        echo "</nav>";
    }

}
```

**WP_Query Loop:**

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
        $paged = 1;
}
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => $src_post_grid, 
    'showposts' => $post_num,
    'paged'     => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $wp_query->the_post();
```

**The Function Call:**

```
$img .= "<div class='navigation'>" . 
    custom_pagination( $custom_query->max_num_pages, "", $paged ) . 
    "</div>";

return $img;
```

All that shows in the source code is this:

```
<div class='navigation'></div>
```

Comment: At first glance you are passing `$custom_query->max_num_pages` as an argument to your pagination function while your query results are stored in `$wp_query` instead of `$custom_query`.